# How to save the login credentials for github on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, github, credentials

I'm using git on a Ubuntu/Debian machine.
I know how to config user informations (name, mail) for repositories.
But with a private github repository, it always require a token each time I push or pull to/from remote.
[image]
This is repetitive, so I wonder if there's a solution to this. I think that the token can ben save somewhere and automatic login like the github desktop on Window.

I searched google but didn't find out solution.

Many thanks for suggestions!

Comment: I'd use SSH for cloning: `git clone git@github.com:username/repo`. You'll need to create an SSH key for this to work, and add it to the github account. Then everything should work automatically.

Comment: I use SSH to connect to GitHub. That allows you to store a locally generated key in your GitHub account which is used for authentication. This article has all the info: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [the official instructions of Github on SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh) worked for me
It contains 2 steps:

1. [Generating a new SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key)

   ```bash
   ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
   > Generating public/private ALGORITHM key pair.
   > Enter a file in which to save the key (/home/YOU/.ssh/id_ALGORITHM):[Press enter]
   > Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
   > Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]
   eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
   ```
2. [Adding the new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account#adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-account)

   ```bash
   cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
   # Then select and copy the contents of the id_ed25519.pub file
   # displayed in the terminal to your clipboard
   ```

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Answer (score 2):

SSH is the best suited method, however, you can use git credential for storing :

- [temporarily](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) with `$git config credential.helper 'cache [<options>]'`

or

- [permanently](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) with `$git config credential.helper 'store [<options>]'`

Comment: what do the <options> mean? What are my options? What am I supposed to put in there?